# DownloadStringAsync 300 URLs in Parallel - C#

Tags: c#, download, webclient

**Description:**

I want to download multiple URL's (around 300) using WebClient's DownloadStringAsync, some of the URL's downloaded fine but for some others the download just hangs forever.

**Questions:**

1. How can I catch the problematic urls that cannot be downloaded?
2. Based on the attached code, How can I implement a timeout period for the 'DownloadStringAsync' method to skip the Url's that cannot be downloaded?

I have googled for solutions but come up shorthanded. Then attempted to search for a solution in the database here with same results. Any help is appreciated.

This is the code I'm using:

```
public class ParallelDownloading
    {
        private int _totalDownloadedURLs = 0;
        private ConcurrentQueue<DownloadFile> _queueToDownlaod;
        private IList<Task> _downloadingTasks;
        private Timer _downloadTimer;

        public event EventHandler<OnFileDownloadCompletedEventArgs> OnDownloadURLCompleted;

        private int _parallelDownloads;

        public ParallelDownloading(int parallelDownloads)
        {
            _totalDownloadedURLs = 0;
            _queueToDownlaod = new ConcurrentQueue<DownloadFile>();
            _downloadingTasks = new List<Task>();
            _downloadTimer = new Timer();

            _parallelDownloads = parallelDownloads;

            ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = parallelDownloads;
        }

        public void StartParallelDownloading()
        {
            _downloadTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DownloadTimer_Elapsed);
            _downloadTimer.Interval = 800;
            _downloadTimer.Start();
        }

        public void EnqueueFileToDownload(DownloadFile file)
        {
            _queueToDownlaod.Enqueue(file);
        }

        void DownloadTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            StartDownload();
        }

        private void StartDownload()
        {
            lock (_downloadingTasks)
            {
                if (_downloadingTasks.Count < _parallelDownloads && _queueToDownlaod.Count > 0)
                {
                    DownloadFile fileToDownload;
                    if (_queueToDownlaod.TryDequeue(out fileToDownload))
                    {
                        var task = new Task(() =>
                        {
                            var client = new WebClient();
                            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
                            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(fileToDownload.Link), fileToDownload.Link);

                        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

                        task.ContinueWith(DownloadOverCallback, TaskContinuationOptions.None);

                        _downloadingTasks.Add(task);
                        task.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            _totalDownloadedURLs ++;
            if (e.Error == null && e.Cancelled == false)
            {
                //do something
            }
            OnFileDownloadCompletedEventArgs evtArgs = new OnFileDownloadCompletedEventArgs();
            evtArgs.DownloadedFiles = _totalDownloadedURLs;
            OnDownloadURLCompleted(this, evtArgs);
        }

        public void DownloadOverCallback(Task downloadingTask)
        {
            lock (_downloadingTasks)
            {
                _downloadingTasks.Remove(downloadingTask);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: That's probably a network or server issue.

Comment: `_totalDownloadedURLs ++` is a race condition that's going to mess up on you under load because `client_DownloadStringCompleted` can be called concurrently from different threads. Consider `Interlocked.Increment`.

Comment: @SLaks def not a network issue.

Comment: @spender could you maybe give a snippet example?

Answer (score 0):

1.How can I catch the problematic urls that cannot be downloaded?
for this you can use try, catch for see what is happen there

2.Based on the attached code, How can I implement a timeout period for the 'DownloadStringAsync' method to skip the Url's that cannot be downloaded?
easiest way is use a Timer to call CancelAsync after a period of time or use the HttpWebRequest, which has a Timeout property

Answer (score 0):

Use `HTTPClient` instead - it is the more modern API and it supports CancellationTokens to allow you to skip URLs after a certain amount of time.

Do not use Webclient, unless you have a good reason for it.